# how to concatenate dataframes as new group?

Tags: python, pandas

kind of new to pandas.

I have

```
df1 = pd.Dataframe(
    [
    {'a': 1},
    {'a': 2},
    {'a': 3},
    ]
)

df2 = pd.Dataframe(
    [
    {'a': 4},
    {'a': 5},
    ]
)
```

I want

```
 df_id  a
 1      1
        2
        3
 2      4
        5
```

Assume I have a list of dfs like `df1` and `df2`. What is the correct way to get the result df?

Am I supposed to also declare some column as a key? or a primary key? Notice that I want to retain the option to slice this dataframe by `df_id` to get back the original dfs.

Also, what is this operation called? I didn't even know what to search for.

Comment: Use `pd.concat([df1, df2])`.

Comment: This [this fantastic answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101) is a great resource for those times when you're trying to merge dfs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=[1,2])` if you want to keep everything for later re-use:

```
     a
1 0  1
  1  2
  2  3
2 0  4
  1  5
```

or if you want to drop the original indexes:

`pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=[1,2]).droplevel(1)`

```
   a
1  1
1  2
1  3
2  4
2  5
```

Comment: How would I make the `keys` automatic?

Comment: `keys` takes a list, so just form a list with whatever you want in the first level of the index